# Do not receive certain PHP error messages

Tags: php

I am running Apache/PHP locally, and *do* receive errors in many cases, like uninitialized variables - but I have noticed a few cases where I do not receive error messages and am wondering if this is normal OR if I am missing out on anything,

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

$1a = "Hello world!";
echo $1a;

?>
```

Also producing no error:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function a()
{
 $b = 5;
 echo $b;
}}

a();

?>
```

Does this script product PHP errors **as it should** for you? If so, I am wondering why I receive none. This is not an error I am likely to make, but there have been other times where I receive a blank page like above, where I would like some sort of feedback.

Comment: Have you checked with `phpinfo()` to see if those ini_set calls are actually succeeding. If they did, the "local setting" would show 1/e_all. But otherwise, yes, you should get the usual "unexpected T_LNUMBER" error from that code snippet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calls to `ini_set` never get executed, because the error happens in the parsing phase (i.e. before anything gets executed). You need to set those configuration values earlier in .htaccess, httpd.conf or php.ini.

Comment: This explains it. In my php.ini I had set 'display errors' to 'Off' and removed 'error_reporting' so that I could mimic many remote hosts set up, which do not display errors. Now I will set this in .htaccess instead of at the beginning of PHP scripts when I am developing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Open up `php.ini`, and CTRL-F for [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) - is it set to on? When I installed php I used `ini_set();` to try and see errors and it didn't work, but editing the `php.ini` file worked.

Edit: I looked at your `phpinfo()` output on the page you posted, and it's set to off. Turn it on if you can. If I recall correctly, you have to restart apache after you edit it.

Edit2: In your `php.ini` file, [error_reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) should be set to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` (default), `E_ALL | E_STRICT` (development), or `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` (production). Honestly, that's all gibberish to me - but if it helps, mine is set to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED`, and I recieved errors from your code.

Comment: Yes, this worked but since the other explained the phenomena of PHPs behavior I gave it the answer.